# "ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare'" hook when running local mobile auto tests

Tags: node.js, appium, webdriver-io, wdio

I'm a beginner, so therefore do not judge strictly for extra information

This is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.11.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.11.2",
    "appium": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "appium-uiautomator2-driver": "^2.29.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  }
}
```

This is wdio.conf.js:

```
export const config = {

    runner: 'local',
    
    port: 4724,
    path: '/',
    specs: [
        './local_test.js'
    ],
    
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],

    maxInstances: 10,

    capabilities: [{
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:platformVersion": "11",
        "appium:deviceName": "Redmi Note 11",
        "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
        "appium:app": "C:\\VisualSC\\i_g_3_YT\\WikipediaSample.apk",
        "appium:udid": "my_udid",
      }],

    logLevel: 'error',

    bail: 0,

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',

    waitforTimeout: 20000,

    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,

    connectionRetryCount: 3,

    services: ['appium'],
    

    framework: 'mocha',

    reporters: ['spec'],


    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },


}
```

And I use the Appium GUI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4rQm.png)

I entered this into the terminal

PS C:\VisualSC\i_g_3_YT> npm run wdio

And It turns out that such an error occurs when running the code:

```
2023-06-25T23:43:13.006Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (file:///C:/VisualSC/i_g_3_YT/node_modules/@wdio/appium-service/build/launcher.js:116:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

Continue...
[0-0] Error: "ts-node/esm/transpile-only 'resolve'" did not call the next hook in its chain and did not explicitly signal a short circuit. If this is intentional, include `shortCircuit: true` in the hook's return.
[0-0]     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
[0-0]     at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:846:13)
[0-0]     at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:7)
[0-0] FAILED

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install ts-node via

`npm install ts-node --save-dev`